# Creating temp file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [x86_64-linux].

When trying to creating a temp file using the tempfile gem, it's getting stuck, and I can't exit from it:

```
1.8.7 :003 > require 'rubygems'
1.8.7 :004 >  require 'tempfile'
1.8.7 :005 > tmp_file = Tempfile.new("new_file")
```

After the last line, it's stuck and not responsive.

I think it works with newer Ruby versions, but does anyone know what can cause this issue?

Comment: What is the value of `$SAFE` and `Dir::tmpdir`?

Comment: $SAFE=0, and Dir::tmpdir r= "/tmp"

Comment: Try: `Tempfile.new('new_file', File.expand_path('.'))`.

Comment: Didn't help .. still the same problem

Comment: Ok, then the next set of questions: What do you get with `Tempfile::MAX_TRY`? Also, what'll happen if you run `File.exist?('/tmp/anything')` (naive check, but worth a try). Also try setting `Tempfile::MAX_TRY = 0` and see whether anything has changed.

Comment: Tempfile::MAX_TRY = 10.
the exists check works, and nothing changes when you try to
Tempfile::MAX_TRY = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' not gone be easy to find an issue without some deeper debugging. Try running:

```
class Tempfile
  def initialize(basename, tmpdir=Dir::tmpdir)
    if $SAFE > 0 and tmpdir.tainted?
      tmpdir = '/tmp'
    end

    lock = nil
    n = failure = 0

    begin
      puts 'Entering critcal stage'
      Thread.critical = true
      begin
        tmpname = File.join(tmpdir, make_tmpname(basename, n))
        lock = tmpname + '.lock'
        n += 1
        puts n 
      end while @@cleanlist.include?(tmpname) or
        File.exist?(lock) or File.exist?(tmpname)

      Dir.mkdir(lock)
    #rescue
    #  failure += 1
    #  retry if failure < MAX_TRY
    #  raise "cannot generate tempfile `%s'" % tmpname
    ensure
      Thread.critical = false
      puts 'critical stage left'
    end

    @data = [tmpname]
    @clean_proc = Tempfile.callback(@data)
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, @clean_proc)

    @tmpfile = File.open(tmpname, File::RDWR|File::CREAT|File::EXCL, 0600)
    @tmpname = tmpname
    @@cleanlist << @tmpname
    @data[1] = @tmpfile
    @data[2] = @@cleanlist

    super(@tmpfile)

    Dir.rmdir(lock)
  end
end
```

This should be identical to your Tempfile `initialize` method, with some debugging bits. Could you run this, and retry creating a new tempfile. I'll update answer when you comment with the console output.

Comment: I ran it with strace, and it keep telling that:
stat("/tmp/thistempfile.lock", 0x7fff20e80070) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tmp/thistempfile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0

Comment: @gal - Have you run it `Tempfile.new` after loading the code above? _ it should throw maximum of one error.

Comment: @gal - This is not code I have written by myself, this is implementation of Tempfile `initialize` method for Ruby 1.8.7 patch 330, which I believe is your ruby version?

Comment: In your command line type `gem which tempfile` - it will give you a path to a 'tempfile.rb` file.

Comment: I found that someone manually edited the file and put: 
tmpname = '/tmp/thistempfile'
and it caused endless loop :(

Comment: @gal - Wow, this is pretty insane! Good spot!